# How to center lists while keeping the left oriented

Tags: css

I want to center a set of  while keeping them left oriented.  You can view the site here.  I used padding to move the subbullets and don't want to mess up the indentions on those either. Here is the site's url.

http://104.236.190.78/partners/

thanks for any help.

```
<ul>
    <li style="text-align: left;">BS in Chemical Engineering &amp; Economics (1985).</li>
    <li style="text-align: left;">MBA from the Wharton School (1991).</li>
     <li style="text-align: left;">Texas Instruments: Manufacturing Engineering Manager (Dallas, 1985-1991).</li>
    <li>Investment Banking (1990-2003).
 <div id = "indent">
    <ul>
    <li style="text-align: left;">DLJ: Technology and Healthcare Investment Banking (NYC &amp; Dallas, 1990-2000).</li>
<li style="text-align: left;">SG Cowen: Technology Investment Banking &amp; Head of Dallas Office (Dallas, 2000-2003).</li>
<li style="text-align: left;">50 completed transactions, including public      and private financings as well as M&amp;A transactions.</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>


#indent{
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code here. Links die/become out of date.

Comment: Include the relative code here, in this post, for others to see. We're not trying to surf the web--we are already distracted enough with stackoverflow addiction.

Comment: {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to a box model
Use a div to center your left justified list

div style='margin:0 auto; width:88%;'>

list item content

I hope this helps
jOsHua JoSepH BIssoT